# SF Movie where different ships are sent to find a habitable world for humanity

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I recall that the Earth is dying. Different ships were sent to different planets looking for one that was habitable for humans.

The survivors have to pick which planet to go to and one guy lies in order to get rescued.

The people left on earth receive a couple of transmissions from different planets and must decide which one to go to.

Answer (score 15):

This is a pretty fair description of [Interstellar](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/)

- **Earth is dying** / Check, there's something called the blight attacking all the crops and making the air unbreathable
- **Different ships sent to different planets** / Check, the "Lazarus Project" involves multiple ships going to various potentially habitable planets.
- **The guy lies to get rescued** / Check, a major plot-point is that Dr Mann lies to get himself rescued, despite having been hailed as a paragon by the other scientists.

Comment: not interstellar

Comment: The people left on earth receive a couple of transmissions from different planets and must decide which 1 to go to.

Comment: @Deb - Since this film is a pretty good match (even after you've commented on why it's not a match), can you offer any additional detail?

Comment: Maybe that was it. I'll have to rewatch it.

Comment: It wasn't even that long ago :P

Comment: It sure sounds like Interstellar (which is AWESOME, btw).  Look up some clips on youtube and see if they ring any bells.  On a side note, can't wait to see Matt Damon portraying a more admirable astronaut in The Martian.  :-)

Answer (score -2):

No it was a TV show Defying Gravity

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if it explained why **Defying Gravity** is a match.  It's also helpful to include an image or video so people can see the characters.  And a plot summary in general.